Cutadapt says low proportion of reads contain primer
I have received raw demultiplexed FASTQ files from an Illumina NovaSeq 6000 2*250 bp sequencing run of CO1 amplicon libraries. Meaning the libraries were prepared with a forward and a reverse primer framing the sequence of interest (~313 bp), and it is these primers that I am now trying to remove with cutadapt. The problem is that I get something like this:
Total read pairs processed:          3,763,074
  Read 1 with adapter:               2,198,188 (58.4%)
  Read 2 with adapter:               2,213,998 (58.8%)

Cutadapt is telling me that only slightly above half of my reads contain the primer. It should either be close to 100% if the files haven't already been adapter-trimmed, or close to 0%, if they have. I have tried adjusting the parameters; with or without anchoring, raising the error rate cutoff, added the reverse complement of the primers to the -a and -A flags to account for read-through (even though with the amplicon length it shouldn't occur) etc, but it only ever changes the outcome negligibly. All reads are 243 bp, i.e. seemingly unprocessed, only missing the 8 bp index as they should. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Here is my original command:
cutadapt -g ^GGWACWGGWTGAACWGTWTAYCCYCC -G ^TANACYTCNGGRTGNCCRAARAAYCA -m 1 -n 2 -e 0.1 -j 0 -o output_1.fastq.gz -p output_2.fastq.gz input_1.fastq.gz input_1.fastq.gz


Please show a few of your pre-trimmed reads. It's likely that that your problem can be fixed by a deeper inspection of the reads themselves. Here's something that will fetch reads, skipping the first 25k reads (to remove some low-quality reads at the start of a flow cell).
zcat input_1.fastq.gz | head -n 100000 | tail -n 20 > sample_1.fastq; zcat input_2.fastq.gz | head -n 100000 | tail -n 20 > sample_2.fastq
